# Sorting List in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I am new to Laravel. I have a List that is being returned as an array in Blade

called personType, but the keys are all out of order.

I see the List being generated in the controller like this:

```
$personTypeList = PersonType::lists('per_type', 'id');
```

But this returns an array that is unsorted. I've tried ksort( $personTypeList) but it causes an error.

Anybody can shine a light on what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about adding an orderBy?

```
$personTypeList = PersonType::orderBy('per_type', 'desc')->lists('per_type', 'id');
```

Comment: um... patience, grasshopper?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method sort available when you are dealing with collections in laravel.

```
//will sort the collection by values, in ASC order.
$personTypeList = PersonType::lists('per_type', 'id') -> sort();
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score -1):

You need to cast the collection to an Array.

`$personTypeList = ['' => ''] + PersonType::lists('per_type', 'id')->toArray();`